# ADO.Net Entity Data Model Designer: Disable auto-layout?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, ado.net, ado.net-entity-data-model

ADO.Net Entity Data Model Designer (VS2010) is making me INSANE -- hopefully someone has dealt with this and knows how to make it stop.

When initially putting together a complex data model, it's perfectly fine that Designer figures out on its own where the lines delineating associations are placed.  However, eventually, I wind up meticulously placing those lines myself for the sake of readability.

But if I finish my layout, and then decide to, say, add a property to an existing entity, Designer redoes my entire layout, or at least every association line that leads to or from that entity.

Is there some way to disable or otherwise get around this automatic layout feature?

Comment: Have you ever considered submitting a Connect item or Visual Studio Uservoice suggestion for this?

Comment: I'd actually never even seen the UserVoice site before.  Have just added a request; please, everyone, vote for it! :)  http://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio/suggestions/3802646-allow-auto-layout-in-ado-net-entity-model-designer

Comment: Oh -- and that doesn't mean I'm no longer interested in an answer :)

Comment: In this case I think all I could do to help you is to vote in Visual Studio Uservoice. Just casted 3 votes. :)

Comment: that's why I don't use it - I'm not sure if that constitutes as an answer though :). Seriously, w/ things like that, I'm not sure you can do anything. Sorting out things on the screen is a relatively complex algorithm, I guess they don't want to add extra work by keeping it compatible w/ previous layout

Comment: Visual Studio 2013 / 2015 has greatly improved the Entity Data Model Designer.  Recommend you upgrade if you haven't already.